# postgresql extracting function source

Tags: postgresql, metadata, pgadmin, psql

Need to extract the source of a PostgreSQL function using SQL.

I am seeing this odd behavior with one of the function, all other functions (around 200+ ) work absolutely fine.

When I run the following statement, it works:

```
select prosrc  from pg_proc where proname= 'accounts_count';
```

However when I run the following, it returns an empty string:

```
select  routine_definition
from    information_schema.routines
where   specific_name = 'accounts_count_66243'
```

PostgreSQL version 8.3. I have tried using both pgAdmin III and psql.

Not a show stopper, but would be useful to know why this might be.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What does `select length(routine_definition)...` return?

Comment: Since 8.4, there is `pg_get_functiondef()`. Maybe another reason to update to a more up-to-date version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look on definition of information_schema.routines, then you can find following filter:

```
FROM pg_namespace n, pg_proc p, pg_language l, pg_type t, pg_namespace nt
 WHERE n.oid = p.pronamespace AND p.prolang = l.oid AND p.prorettype = t.oid 
   AND t.typnamespace = nt.oid AND (pg_has_role(p.proowner, 'USAGE'::text) 
    OR has_function_privilege(p.oid, 'EXECUTE'::text));
```

so my theory:

- there are some issue in rights and ownership of related function (probably) - try to use different account for validation of this theory (postgres is best)

Comment: Well done. It turned out to be a rights issue. The function owner was set to a different user. It appears if the function is not owned by the logged in user, information_schema.routines does not surface the source while pg_proc does. Odd.